# Should a Statement of Purpose cover Purpose or Capability or Both?

Tags: statement-of-purpose

I am applying for OMSA degree from Georgia Tech and the application requires me to submit a 4000-character long Statement of Purpose.
My question is this:
Should a SOP cover my capability and show me as someone who can clear the course, or should a SOP cover why I am interested in the degree and how it will help me in my career?
This is what the website says:

> **Personal statements**
>
> - Goals and career plans, and reason for applying to this program. Up
>   to 4,000 characters allowed for response.
> - Other graduate programs to which you are applying
> - Statement of purpose

Comment: _some1_ — Oh god.  Kill this habit now.  Burn it with fire.  Nuke it from orbit.  If this creeps into your statement of purpose, you won't get in anywhere.  The word is spelled "someone".

Answer (score 3):

Your statement of purpose should include exactly what they request: "goals and career plans, and reason for applying to this program".